# Lit-Elements external js file as storage changed by a property data binding

Tags: javascript, polymer-starter-kit, polymer-3.x, lit-element

i try to use in lit-elements a external js file for init values but if i do so, it isnt changebel anymore via property binding. if i write it without the extanal storage file just use this. scope and declare it in the constructor, everything works fine. But as an external file not ... ?:/

but why?

i have two files menu.js:

```
import { LitElement, html } from '@polymer/lit-element';
import '@polymer/iron-pages/iron-pages.js';
import './main.js'
import { store } from './store'

class MenuElement extends LitElement {

  constructor() {
    super()
    this.page = 0;
    this.ninjas = ['Ninja1', 'Ninja2', 'Ninja3']
    this.log()
  }
  static get properties() {
    return {
      page: {
        type: Number
      },
      header: String,
      ninjas: Array,
      store: {
        type: Object,
        page: {
          type: Number
        }
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    return html`
      <style>
        /* :host {
          border: solid 10px blue;
        } */
        ::slotted(h3) {
          border: solid 1px red
        }
      </style>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li @click="${ (e) => { this.changePage2(e) } }">Home</li>
          <li @click="${ (e) => { this.changePage(e) } }">Page</li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
          ${this.ninjas.map(i => html`<li>${i}</li>`)}
        </ul>
      </div>

      <iron-pages selected="${ store.page }">
        <slot name="lala"></slot>
        <div><slot name="testSlot"></slot> Page 0</div>
        <main-view></main-view>
      </iron-pages>

    `;
  }

  changePage() {
    store.page = 1;
    console.log(store.page)
  }
  changePage2() {
    store.page = 0;
    console.log(store.page)
  }
  log() {
    console.log(store)
    console.log(store.page)
  }
}
customElements.define('app-menu', MenuElement);
```

and b store.js

```
export let store = {
  page: 1
}
```

thank You for any ideas =)

Comment: Why not just set `this.page = 1` in the constructor? Or `this.page = store.page`?

Comment: the point is i try to do the same like redux is doing and so i try to build a dynamic menu so that i have for changes just to edit 1 file and not the view and the controller.

Comment: I would just do `this.page = store.page` in the constructor.

Comment: yes for the menu it works fine thanks!!! haven't seen that idea.
but this isn't working for changes between different views, like redux (what my actually target is) is doing.

Comment: Ya this isn't the way to do it if you want changes to `store` in this view to affect another. In each view they will have their own version of store. You will need to create a higher order component that passes the same reference to both places. Redux stores are (essentially) a function that stores an object and has prescribed methods for interacting with it.

Comment: You could also use the Redux helper for litElement found [here](https://github.com/Polymer/pwa-helpers#redux-helpers)

Comment: yes i saw that coming. so i try my best to get closer to redux to understand redux a bit better. but yes the question above is clear thx !!!

Comment: yes, I've tried it before and this is the actually goal but i'm not ready enough (by understanding redux under the hood) to implement redux right now.

Answer (score 0):

To quote dracco

> Actually it's not about JS, every objective language can have a collection structure, but modifying the collection does not modify the object.
>   Comparing in JS means comparing references (it would be impossible to make a universal and fast content comparison), so pushing things to an array keeps the reference the same (as it is still the same instance of an Array class) - just the contents change.
>   Similarly in class Person { constructor() { this.isBanned = false; } }, if you create a new instance (const p = new Person();) and then modify the property (p.isBanned = true;), it is still the same instance it was before, just the property differs.

You can read the full story at https://open-wc.org/faq/rerender.html

In the object reference for the external store never changes and therefore no render is triggered.

### What you can do

#### Trigger it manually

with something like this

```
changePage() {
  store.page = 1;
  this.requestUpdate();
}
```

#### Use a state library

For example

- https://github.com/adobe/lit-mobx
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/lit-robot
- ...

they, of course, all come with their own set of rules and know how.